# jQuery only defined in contentScripts?

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon-sdk

Is jQuery only available in contentScripts? like

```
tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScript: 'jQuery("body").html("<img src=\'' + imgdata + '\' />")'
});
```

cos when I try using jQuery outside, I get "jQuery is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is correct. The contentScripts are the only ones that have access to the actual page. You may want to check out PageMods as well.

Comment: It is worth noting that pagemods and page content via tabs are the only places jQuery makes sense. In your add-on code ( main.js and modules ) there *is no DOM*. What I tend to do when using the page-mod module is add jQuery as a contentScriptFile as well as other scripts containing jQuery code from my data folder.